# GetUserMedia (WebRTC) error on IOS 14.3 Safari: NotAllowedError

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to test my simple voice chat on an iPhone 12 Max running IOS 14.3. However, I keep getting this error:

```
"NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."
```

As mentioned in the title, I am on Safari, and what's odd to me is that when I test this on my iPad Pro (also running on IOS 14.3), the call to GetUserMedia works, and the voice is played (the peer connection is set up).

On another note, does this have anything to do with Ice Candidates? When I look in the other peer's console (a Windows 10 computer on Chrome) it is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Error processing ICE candidate
```

And I know when I go to the site on a Mac OSX device I have to enable ICE Candidates. Is something like that happening here?

Also, going to [the official WebRTC examples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/) also gives me the same error.

Is it just my device? Will this happen with other devices? How can I fix this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sounds like its just your device. I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 14.3 installed, WebRTC is working fine. Try to load your webpage in chrome and check the app permissions in your iOS settings.

Comment: @imaginate did you find a solution for the problem? I get the same error.

Comment: @umutcanturan I did not. However, I know this has something to do with Safari being weird when it comes to ice candidates because safari blocks them on the computer and has to be re-enabled. However, I'm not sure how applicable that is to this scenario because obviously it's on an iPhone. Sorry I couldn't help